# Codeigniter: How to capture slashes in route and pass to controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to capture slashes from a url and pass them into my controller. Here's an example of my problem:

Let's say I GET `http://localhost/here/is/an/example` where my route looks like:

```
$routes['here/is/(:any)'] = 'my_controller/$1';
```

and I have the following function definition in `my_controller`:

```
public function index($rest_of_the_path) {
...
}
```

**I would like the value of `$rest_of_the_path` to be `'an/example'`, but it actually equals `'an'`.** How can I structure my code so I get what I want?

P.S.: I'm using Codeigniter 2.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
public function index() {
    $rest_of_the_path = implode("/", func_get_args());  
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Can you explain to me how it works? I don't understand how you can call func_get_args() when there aren't any parameters.

Comment: This is what func_get_args() is doing. It is a function in php. For more you can read http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php . You can use it for any function and it works.

Comment: Brilliant. Kind of an ugly way to do it, but better than the alternative. I feel like that with a lot of things in PHP, actually.

Comment: I should have been more specific by saying *when there aren't any parameters in index()*

Comment: I don't know if that helps you, but it is better for routing to follow some known structure to minimize your urls. This article will really help you to achieve that http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-minimize-url-and-remove-index-php/

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help. This is actually supposed to be a REST API, not a website. I'm pulling this part off because I'm going to use the path to create a directory on POST.

Comment: Then yes you are right it doesn't really help :) . Good luck with your REST API, it will take a long time to create it. Check this code perhaps it will help you: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver .

Comment: I'm pretty experienced at building them. This is my second one in CI and I've never had to do this specific thing before. I'm already using that library, it's really good.

Comment: @MikeHoller have you checked out the documentation for the URI class? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: I have, but I really had to do some sculpting to get the data where I wanted it without having any magic numbers, etc. It wasn't too readable. @john-skoumbourdis 's solution is much shorter and can be clarified with a simple comment.